# Is this a correct approach for sending to multiple clients?

Tags: java

I have a server (thread) that receives data and has an array of clients (Sockets). Whenever a client connects a new thread is created and a new client is added to the clients array.

Here is the clients:

```
List<Socket> clients = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Socket>());
```

So then the server send the incoming data to the clients as such:

```
//for each message:
    for(Socket client : clients){ //throws java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
                        new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true).println(line);
                    }
```

Now there are two issues here:

First of all I occasionally get a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException when thread 2 adds a client.

Also I am creating a new `PrintWriter` every time I am sending a message. The other option will be to store a `PrintWriter` for each client but it is a client so it doesn't make sense to store a `PrintWriter`.

Is this a good approach ?

Answer (score 1):

That's correct if all clients are waiting a println with a getString() on their side, else you may want to change to the UDP protocol.

Creating a new PrintWriter everyloop is not necessary, since the connection will be kept open so just one (for each client) is best, also in the client side you will have one only Reader and that one will wait for messages trough its get methods.

For the concurrent problem you must create a copy of the current list:

```
for (Socket client : new ArrayList<>(clients)) {
   new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true).println(line);
}
```

Comment: "Creating a new PrintWriter everyloop is not necessary", so you suggest storing 1 PrintWriter for each client ?

Comment: Yes exactly, usually the approach for using multi clients is also to have a separated thread for each one (so you don't block other clients while writing to one)

Comment: Currently I have a new thread that listen for new clients and adds them to the array. After that the other server takes over and loops through the array. Sounds good no ?

Comment: It works... but imagine 1million clients, you will have each one waiting until the loop completes to receive a new message

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to a object (`client.getOutputStream()`) while iterating over the list thus the `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. Change your `List<>` for a `ConcurrentLinkedQueue`. Also for `PrintWriter` here you just wrap an existing stream.